# Android WebView with WebKit

Tags: android, webkit, android-webview

I want to use the same HTML5 with JS app on few platforms -- Windows (JavaFX), iOS (Objective C) and Android. We've chosen to use WebKit for iOS and JavaFX to render the web page. The problem is from Android API 19 it is using its own engine from Chromium for WebView.

Is it possible to force Android WebView in API 19 or higher to use WebKit as web engine instead of Chromium with Blink?